# Group and subtract all rows in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Consider the following example:

```
t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 
A  4  6  7  8  5
A  3  6  8  1  4
A  2  3  5  3  1
A  3  4  3  1  3
B  3  6  8  3  4
B  3  9  3  7  3
B  5  2  3  2  1
```

I hope to get a dataframe which checks for differences between every pair of rows possible within a group (A and B seperately).

I have been trying to subset the dataframe based on a loop and manually calculate the differences between rows. This is leading to a lot of computation and it is hard to manage the referencing after all the differences have been calculated. I am basically ending up with several lists.

The resulting dataframe needs to contain the row differences for all possible row combinations(or permutations?) within a group.

For example, for B, without considering the first column i.e. characters, the following is the expected result:

```
t2 t3 t4 t5 t6
0  -3  5 -4  1
-2  4  5  1  3
-2  7  0  5  2
```

The sign is not very important. Only the magnitude

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: could you shpw what your output is supposed to look like? I dont quite get what you mean with `differences between every pair of rows`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to get a table with a row showing the difference between every pair of rows in each group. For example, row 2 of this output shows row 1 of the input minus row 3 of the input.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df) # convert to data.table

df[, {  pairs <- CJ(row1 = 1:.N, row2 = 1:.N)[row1 != row2]
        data.table(pairs + .I[1] - 1, .SD[pairs[[1]]] - .SD[pairs[[2]]])
  }, by = t1]



#     t1 row1 row2 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6
#  1:  A    1    2  1  0 -1  7  1
#  2:  A    1    3  2  3  2  5  4
#  3:  A    1    4  1  2  4  7  2
#  4:  A    2    1 -1  0  1 -7 -1
#  5:  A    2    3  1  3  3 -2  3
#  6:  A    2    4  0  2  5  0  1
#  7:  A    3    1 -2 -3 -2 -5 -4
#  8:  A    3    2 -1 -3 -3  2 -3
#  9:  A    3    4 -1 -1  2  2 -2
# 10:  A    4    1 -1 -2 -4 -7 -2
# 11:  A    4    2  0 -2 -5  0 -1
# 12:  A    4    3  1  1 -2 -2  2
# 13:  B    5    6  0 -3  5 -4  1
# 14:  B    5    7 -2  4  5  1  3
# 15:  B    6    5  0  3 -5  4 -1
# 16:  B    6    7 -2  7  0  5  2
# 17:  B    7    5  2 -4 -5 -1 -3
# 18:  B    7    6  2 -7  0 -5 -2
```

This is a little redundant since it also shows row 3 - row 1 (which is just the negative). If you don't want this duplication, change `row1 != row2` to `row1 < row2`.

```
df[, {  pairs <- CJ(row1 = 1:.N, row2 = 1:.N)[row1 < row2]
        data.table(pairs + .I[1] - 1, .SD[pairs[[1]]] - .SD[pairs[[2]]])
  }, by = t1]

#    t1 row1 row2 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6
# 1:  A    1    2  1  0 -1  7  1
# 2:  A    1    3  2  3  2  5  4
# 3:  A    1    4  1  2  4  7  2
# 4:  A    2    3  1  3  3 -2  3
# 5:  A    2    4  0  2  5  0  1
# 6:  A    3    4 -1 -1  2  2 -2
# 7:  B    5    6  0 -3  5 -4  1
# 8:  B    5    7 -2  4  5  1  3
# 9:  B    6    7 -2  7  0  5  2
```

Explanation:

`CJ(a, b)` generates a data.table with a row for all possible pairs of values (a[i], b[j]). Example:

```
CJ(1:3, 1:3)
#    V1 V2
# 1:  1  1
# 2:  1  2
# 3:  1  3
# 4:  2  1
# 5:  2  2
# 6:  2  3
# 7:  3  1
# 8:  3  2
# 9:  3  3
```

Since it is a data.table, you can subset by using non-$-prefixed column names in `[]`, example

```
CJ(a = 1:3, b = 1:3)[a < b]
#    a b
# 1: 1 2
# 2: 1 3
# 3: 2 3
```

Within the `j` part of `dt[i, j, k]`, the variable `.SD` is the entire data.table subset to the given group (groups determined by the grouping vars in k). So this answer takes the first element of each pair, selects the rows of the group corresponding to those elements `.SD[pairs[[1]]]`, and subtracts from that the rows of the group corresponding to the other element of each pair `.SD[pairs[[2]]]`. A data.table is created with `pairs` and the output of this subtraction. This is done for each group, and data.table automatically rbinds all the group outputs together.

Comment: Thanks! I've been getting the following error with this method
Error in `[.data.frame`(dt, , { : unused argument (by = t1)

Comment: My fault, I forgot to include this line of code `setDT(df)`, to be run before everything else, which converts your data frame to a data.table, allowing you to use these operations (which only work on data.tables)

Comment: It worked and thanks a lot! I tried to fix the problem earlier but I am not familiar with data.table. Pretty complicated. Now I need to study this command! Is there a possibility to break all the commands down to more basic ones so that anyone else reading this post may easily understand whats happening?

Comment: Added an explanation.  Also, the creators of data.table have a [good intro](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html) on their CRAN page.

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse`, you can use a Cartesian join within each `t1`:

```
dat %>% 
gather(key, value, -grp) %>% 
left_join(gather(dat, key, value, - grp), by = "grp") %>% 
mutate(diff = value.x - value.y)

  grp key.x value.x key.y value.y diff
1   A    t2       4    t2       4    0
2   A    t2       4    t2       3    1
3   A    t2       4    t2       2    2
4   A    t2       4    t2       3    1
5   A    t2       4    t3       6   -2
6   A    t2       4    t3       6   -2
```

Note that since my brain doesn't always comply I relabeled `t1` as `grp`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option. We split the dataframe by group, then we find every combo of rows per group, then we map out the differences and rejoin.

```
library(tidyverse)


testDat %>%
  group_by(t1) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  split(.$t1) %>%
  map(
    ~nest(., data = -c(t1, row)) %>%
      list(.,.) %>%
      reduce(full_join, by = "t1") %>%
      rename(row1 = row.x, row2 = row.y, vec1 = data.x, vec2 = data.y) %>%
      filter(row1 != row2) %>%
      mutate(diff = map2(vec1, vec2, ~unlist(.x)-unlist(.y)))%>%
      select(-vec1, -vec2) %>%
      unnest_wider(col = diff)
    ) %>%
  bind_rows()
#> # A tibble: 18 x 8
#> # Groups:   t1 [2]
#>    t1     row1  row2    t2    t3    t4    t5    t6
#>    <chr> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 A         1     2     1     0    -1     7     1
#>  2 A         1     3     2     3     2     5     4
#>  3 A         1     4     1     2     4     7     2
#>  4 A         2     1    -1     0     1    -7    -1
#>  5 A         2     3     1     3     3    -2     3
#>  6 A         2     4     0     2     5     0     1
#>  7 A         3     1    -2    -3    -2    -5    -4
#>  8 A         3     2    -1    -3    -3     2    -3
#>  9 A         3     4    -1    -1     2     2    -2
#> 10 A         4     1    -1    -2    -4    -7    -2
#> 11 A         4     2     0    -2    -5     0    -1
#> 12 A         4     3     1     1    -2    -2     2
#> 13 B         1     2     0    -3     5    -4     1
#> 14 B         1     3    -2     4     5     1     3
#> 15 B         2     1     0     3    -5     4    -1
#> 16 B         2     3    -2     7     0     5     2
#> 17 B         3     1     2    -4    -5    -1    -3
#> 18 B         3     2     2    -7     0    -5    -2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is making use of `outer`

```
f1 <- function(dat) {
  m1 <- outer(seq_len(nrow(dat)), seq_len(nrow(dat)), 
   FUN = Vectorize(function(i, j) list(dat[i, ] - dat[j, ])))
   do.call(rbind, m1[row(m1)!= col(m1)])
 }

do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df1[-1], df1$t1), f1))
```

---

Or using the function with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
     group_split(t1) %>%
     map_dfr(~ .x %>%
         summarise(t1 = first(t1), out = list(f1(.[-1])))) %>% 
     unnest(out)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(t1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), t2 = c(4L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L), t3 = c(6L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 2L), 
    t4 = c(7L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 3L), t5 = c(8L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 7L, 2L), t6 = c(5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L)), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution, where `combn()` is used:

```
dfout <- lapply(split(df,df$t1),
                function(x) do.call(rbind,combn(seq(nrow(x)),2, function(v) x[v[1],-1]-x[v[2],-1],simplify = F)))
```

such that

```
> dfout
$A
   t2 t3 t4 t5 t6
1   1  0 -1  7  1
2   2  3  2  5  4
3   1  2  4  7  2
21  1  3  3 -2  3
22  0  2  5  0  1
31 -1 -1  2  2 -2

$B
   t2 t3 t4 t5 t6
5   0 -3  5 -4  1
51 -2  4  5  1  3
6  -2  7  0  5  2
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(t1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), t2 = c(4L, 
3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L), t3 = c(6L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 9L, 2L), 
    t4 = c(7L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 8L, 3L, 3L), t5 = c(8L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 7L, 2L), t6 = c(5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```